# how to copy layer in after effect and just change this layer text?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

> hello, i'm a beginner in AE. When i copy one layer (that contain
>   text) and paste it , and change this layer's text, in base layer applied
>   and base layer text changed.
>
> i want copy the previous layer and paste it and just change the second's layer text

Comment: Please go through this i will be flagging this question after one hour if no improvement seen, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is very very difficult to understand. If I look at the last sentence "i want [to] copy layer and pas[t]e it and just change this layer['s] text", I can answer by saying: copying any layer and pasting it is done w/cmd-c and cmd-v (alt in windows) just like everything else. If you select another layer the pasted layer will appear directly above the layer selected. You can also duplicate a layer (cmd-d). About changing the text, this is done by double-clicking the text layer and entering the text. Make sure it is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

If you select your Comp1 in the timeline and duplicate it, then you haven't a second comp. You have the same comp working as two layers.

But if you select the Comp1 in the bin project and duplicate it, you have a Comp2 and then you drop it to timeline. In this way you have 2 'real' comps independently.
You can change all the content of the Comp2 without any change in the Comp1.

Source:http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/202/883208